# If the Klingons were supposed to represent the Soviets, what were the Romulans supposed to be?

Tags: star-trek, klingon, romulan

Star Trek made no bones about the Klingons corresponding to the Soviets -- the Soviets were known for claiming invention of things that westerners in fact invented -- I think baseball and lightbulb are two examples and in one movie, the Klingons claim Shakespeare as crazy as that sounds. (Am I wrong?)

But the Romulan could equally be adversaries that correspond to a major American rival -- was an explicit or implied correspondence ever shown?

Comment: Addressed in the dupe. KeithS says that the Romulans represent their namesake, the (Ancient) Romans. Brian says that they represent the Russians also, but the more sneaky, less robust side of their character (e.g. the KGB)

Comment: @Valorum: Actually, Brian also says the Romulans represent the isolationist aspect of the Chinese at the time.